# how can i disable right click on Google map infowindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am loading map in my web application using this code

```
    function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
```

creating infowindow :

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'My Title'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}
```

i have disabled right click on containg div

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

but still on right click on infowindow default context menu is appering.

my question is how can i disable right click on infowindow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a DOM Element for the `content` of your infoWindow rather than a string. Then  you can set events on your element.

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m6JUg/).